# Javascript library for (Bayesian?) time series change point detection

Tags: javascript, statistics, time-series, data-analysis

**Short version of the question:**

Can anybody point me to a javascript library that implements change point detection for time series? (Or at least simplifies the implementation of an algorithm.)

I have looked around but I was unable to find anything. I was thinking of Bayesian approaches but would be happy to try anything. I was hoping to avoid re-inventing the wheel...

*Note:* I am not looking for front-ends for cloud data-analysis services by AWS, IBM, etc. but a library that does the calculations itself.

---

**Long version of the question:**

I have a time-series dataset which results from a random process which jumps between various states:

E.g.:

- state 1: normal distribution with mean1, std1
- state 2: normal distribution with mean2, std2
- ...
- state x: normal distribution with mean_x, std_x

The process remains for some time in a given state before randomly jumping to another, remaining there, before jumping again, etc...

I am looking for a solution that allows me to identify the points at which the process jumps from one state to another.